# Show the minimal polynomial of a normal operator has no repeated roots (over $\mathbb{Q}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

From Axler, here is the question:

Suppose $V$ is an inner-product space. Prove that if $T \in L(V)$ is
normal, then the minimal polynomial of $T$ has no repeated roots.

I managed to show this over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, and my question whether this holds over $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm aware that the term "inner product space" may not be the right word in this case, so to be clear I mean a Vector Space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with a symmetric bilinear form which is positive definite.

Comment: The key is to note that $T$ is diagonalizable over son field extension

Comment: Can you post a full solution please, I'm not too familiar with field extensions but I could read up on them